# Defining a Grassmann Algebra in Python

Tags: programming, clifford-group

I am trying to implement a Grassmann algebra in Python and was wondering if anyone could recommend any packages or suggest how to do so?

I want to define the following multiplication rules over $\Bbb{C}^{2n}$ with standard basis vectors $e_j$ via $$e_j^2=0 \text{ and the anti-commutation rule } e_ie_j+e_je_i=0$$
I then plan on defining an exponential function of quadratic terms in these basis vectors in a way that respects the relations above, ie $\exp{(ie_ae_b)}$, via the power series definition.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions on how to program this!

Comment: This would go better on another of the stackexchanges. The computational science one maybe.

Comment: Sympy can handle noncommutative polynomials so you may want to try there.

Comment: @Rammus thank you! This is very useful!